# How to set <ItemTemplate> to a datasource?

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, itemtemplate, servercontrols

How can I set the datasource of an ItemTemplate? Right now I have one that is wrapped by a datarepeater and that is how I databind to it.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptTotal" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
            <td>Four</td>
                </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant set the datasource for the item template, you can set it for the repeater in the code behind using

```
rptTotal.DataSource = datasourcename
```

Comment: Are there any other controls I can set it to? Does it have to be a repeater? Sometimes I have tables with distinct rows, and I find using a datarepeater a little weird in those cases.

Comment: You can bind data to DropDownLists, or with a little codebehind you can bind textboxes, labels, etc almost anything with it. But if you dont know the number of rows being returned you need to use a control that repeats until all rows are outputted. Also a list of Standard databound controls can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228214.aspx).

Comment: For this case there was always going to be only one row returned. I went with a repeater, even though it seems strrange